# Payoneer Card Application Has Been Declined

Tags: paypal, payment

I've made application for `Payoneer` today but they have rejected my application without any reason. Also, I couldn't log into the account. It says `Account Blocked! (#MA104). Please contact customer support`. Why does this happen?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Paypal Customer service

Comment: @InbarRose Payoneer tag is not in the list. i did not have enough reputation to add new tag. that's why i added payment related tag of paypal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what purpose did you create this app? Personal or business use?

Comment: i'm gonna use this for freelancer.com as they are asking for payment option

Comment: As I can see that you have said you are working for Freelance.com I would suggest that you create a new application using a new email address and make the application through odesk or freelance.com.

Comment: This should be a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: best way is try from Odek first. Once you have the new application using a new email address you can the add the other company to that new account.

Comment: @MaheshWijewardhana as i have already registered with payoneer, can i use same account for odesk?

Comment: No. i think you can't use that account. they will probably have suspended your account. i think you should go to odesk and apply through them using a new email address and they will approve that application.

Comment: @MaheshWijewardhana Thanks. It worked for me. they asked me for Scanned document of my NIC or Driving license for approval.

Answer (score 0):

@JWarker: Hi, my name is Nissim, I'm Head of Community at Payoneer. I saw your question and would be happy to assist you in getting it resolved.

If you submitted an application and it was declined, we would have sent you an e-mail with an explanation of why it was declined. You are more than welcome to reply to that e-mail and we will be able to assist you.

Once you reply to the e-mail, you will receive an automated confirmation with a reference ID number for your inquiry (will start with LTK). If you provide me with that I'd be happy to make sure it's reviewed promptly.

Comment: I am having issues integrating the SDK into my App.

I have posted an issue on the github repository:
https://github.com/Armor-Payments/armor-payments-php/issues/5